# GridsearchCV with big dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am trying to build a classifier with `GridSearchCV` with a huge dataset (2M records * 500 features and growing, expecting at least 15M in total). However, I find that `GridSearchCV.fit`doesn't take generator for X and Y. The problem is I don't have all the memory space for the task. The classifier I use is `SGDClassifier` (which supports `partial_fit`).

Before this I would use a much smaller subset of the dataset for the `GridSearchCV`, and then retrain the best classifier with the whole dataset. Is this the right way to use GridSearchCV?

Comment: So what happens when fitting a single model without GridSearchCV? You got enough memory for that? Regarding GridSearchCV and memory: the probably most important param here is ```pre_dispatch```. Try decreasing the number of pre_dispatched jobs. I think there are also some problems regarding multiprocessing and memory, mostly observed on OX X systems (if i recall correctly; there should be some open issues @github).

Comment: `sgdclassifier` itself can do partial_fit, so I don't have to load whole collection into memory before building the classifier. The current problem is that, before the data is passed into the `fit` method, i am already getting out of memory warning just by trying to load the data into memory.

Comment: I don't think it works like you expect. when running 4 jobs, i suspect GridSearchCV copies the complete data 4 times (and some overhead because of dispatch). The ```partial_fit``` function has no use in this context i think (it's for customized partial-fittings when the memory can't holt the whole data; but a generator-based approach must be implement first). Of course you can implement some highly complex grid-search alternative using partial-fit with shared memory or other approaches.

Comment: yes, i know that after some time lol